# Is there a global setting in ASP.NET WebAPI2 to have the deserialization, JSON & XML, be case insensitive?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, json-deserialization, xml-deserialization

This is preferred because properties in objects are myProp while in C# they are MyProp. So I'd like to have it handle both coming in with their capitalization.

Comment: This link will answer that question https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-mvc-json-output-camelcase-pascalcase/

Comment: @Rav That is interesting but it says how to make the serialization PascalCase. I need to have it handle DEserialization in any case.

Comment: this should work, for deserialisation, or check the options for the ContractResolver 

  JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };

            var model =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result, settings);

Comment: although json.net would handle any case automatically for you when deserialising